# DeviceMotion and DeviceOrientation in WKWebView iOS 13

Tags: ios, wkwebview, ios-permissions, devicemotion

I want to use `DeviceMotion` and `DeviceOrientation` events in `WKWebView` in iOS 13+.
I am using below code

```
<html>
    <style>
        #container{
            margin: 20px; 
            padding: 20px
        }
        #deviceType{
            text-align: center; 
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            font-size: 3rem;
            font-weight: bold; 
            color: #08f
        }
        #permission{
            padding: 2rem 5rem;
            background: #08f;
            color: white; 
            margin-top: 30;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            font-size: 3rem;
            border: none; 
            border-radius: 1rem
        }
        #permissionStatus{
            text-align: center; 
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
            font-size: 2.5rem;
            font-weight: 600; 
            color: red;
            margin-top: 30px
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
                <div id="deviceType"></div>
                <div style="text-align: center">
                    <button id="permission">Ask for permission</button>
                </div>
                <div id="permissionStatus">Pending</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script>

        if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function') {
            document.getElementById('deviceType').innerText = 'iOS 13'
            document.getElementById('permission').addEventListener('click', function () {
                console.log('button clicked')
                DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(response => {

                    // This is showing "denied" without showing any permission popup
                    console.log(response)
                    document.getElementById('permissionStatus').innerText = response

                }).catch(console.error)
            });
        } else {
            // ignore this case for processing
            console.log('non iOS 13')
            document.getElementById('deviceType').innerText = 'non iOS 13'
        }
    </script>
</html>
```

This webpage is working both in safari and chrome and asking permission to use device motion as shown below

Images:

[image: Ask permission on chrome]

Status will be updated based on I click Allow or Cancel

[image]

But in my app inside I am using `WKWebView` and When I press **Ask Permission** Button, It is not showing any alert for asking permission and it is directly setting status to *Denied*. (shown below).

[image]

Please guide me if I am doing something wrong or any extra stuffs required from `WKWebView` side.
Here is my iOS `WKWebView` Code. I don't know if changes in `WKUserContentController` or `WKWebViewConfiguration` are required.

```
self.webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero)
self.webView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

// Add the webview as a subview of MTKView
self.view.addSubview(self.webView)

self.webView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
self.webView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor).isActive = true
self.webView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
self.webView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


let websiteDataTypes = NSSet(array: [WKWebsiteDataTypeDiskCache, WKWebsiteDataTypeMemoryCache])
let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: 0)
WKWebsiteDataStore.default().removeData(ofTypes: websiteDataTypes as! Set<String>, modifiedSince: date, completionHandler:{ })

self?.webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!))
```

Comment: Are you using http or https? Some apis require https. I’ve used motion API in Capacitor apps, which use WKWebView without problems

Comment: I am using https. My project is built with iOS 13 build and XCode 11.2. I am not able to understand why it is not working on my app because both chrome and safari uses WKWebView and same site is working on both. Can you please confirm that same this is working on your side even after building project with new XCode and iOS 13. That would be appreciated.

Comment: We are currently struggling with the same issue. There is an open ticket here, that was created by another guy who has a similar problem: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203287

Comment: Have you tried using `uiDelegate ` ?

Comment: replied this before seeing the answer. This is really really weird but it did work :D
Thank you!

Comment: Well it's not that weird. Read `WKUIDelegate` docs https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview/1415009-uidelegate. It is saying that "presenting native user interface elements on behalf of a webpage". So if webpage needs to show `UIAlertController`, it should confirms this protocol

Comment: My bad, haven't noticed that in the docs. Nice observation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried using `uiDelegate` and it worked

Just added one line inside `viewDidLoad`

```
webView.uiDelegate = self
```

Also you will have to confirm type of `ViewController` to `WKUIDelegate`. That's it

Answer (score 0):

On Xamarin iOS (Xamarin.Forms) you can inject the permission request script with the `EvaluateJavaScript` method on the WkWebView when it is ready:

```
webView.EvaluateJavaScript("DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission().then(response => { if (response == 'granted') {window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => {})}}).catch(console.error)");
```

If using a custom WkWebView renderer the script can be injected when setting the webView control in `OnElementChanged` (must implement IWKUIDelegate if this bug is still around https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=203287)

Example:

```
// do this when setting up the webview control in OnElementChanged
                //enable device motion sensors permission script:
                //https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/how-to-request-device-motion-and-orientation-permission-in-ios-13-74fc9d6cd140
                var source =
                "function requestSensorPermission() {" +
                "   if (typeof(DeviceMotionEvent) !== 'undefined' && typeof(DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission) === 'function') {" +
                "       DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission() .then(response => {" +
                "           if (response == 'granted') { " +
                "               window.addEventListener('devicemotion', (e) => { })" +
                "           }" +
                "       }).catch(console.error)" +
                "   }" +
                "}";
                var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(source), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, true);
                wkWebView.Configuration.UserContentController.AddUserScript(script);
```

Then you can call **yourCustomWebView**.EvaluateJavaScript("requestSensorPermission()") in your code behind when `WkWebView` is ready.

> **EvaluateJavaScript:**
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/webkit.wkwebview.evaluatejavascript?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12
>
> **Custom WkWebView Renderer:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/hybridwebview#create-the-custom-renderer-on-ios